# Embedded Objects - An Object in an Object

Tags: javascript

I need this structure to organize my code...so that I can call it like this

```
Control.Menu
```

Here is my attempt:

```
var Control = 
{
    Menu : menu  
    {
        menu_timer:     0,
        menu_element:   0,

        top_mouse_over: function ( id ) 
        {
            Menu.bottom_mouse_over();
            Menu.menu_element = document.getElementById( id );
            Menu.menu_element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        },
...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Menu : menu  
{
    …
```

What's the `menu` on the right side of the colon for? All you need is this:

```
Menu: {
    …
```

Inside `top_mouse_over()`, `Menu` won't be defined:

```
Menu.bottom_mouse_over(); // This isn’t going to work
```

…it was just a property on the `Control` object; you never created a `Menu` variable anywhere. Instead, you can refer to it as `Control.Menu`, or use the `this` keyword. In a function, `this` is whatever object the function was called as a property of, i.e. the thing to the left of the dot. In this case, if you call it like this:

```
Control.Menu.top_mouse_over(someId);
```

…then inside `top_mouse_over`, `this` will point to `Menu`. You could change the body of the function to this:

```
top_mouse_over: function ( id ) 
{
    this.bottom_mouse_over();
    this.menu_element = document.getElementById( id );
    this.menu_element.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

(If you’re not familiar with `this`, please read up on it before you use it. Until you understand it, it will be easy to make mistakes.)

FWIW, common convention is to capitalize *only* constructors (functions you call with the `new` keyword), and to start anything else with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @stack.user.0 You left a comment about accessing `Menu` from inside `top_mouse_over`, but it disappeared! I added some info on how to do this to my answer.